# Syntax question on use and scope - example from 'Rust by Example'

Tags: rust

I'm totally new to Rust and in the early steps of learning the language.

As such, I'm reading [The book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/title-page.html) while also following along the examples in [Rust by Example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/index.html), and I came across some behavior that puzzles me and I would hope to get an explanation for.

---

The [chapter 3.2.1](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/custom_types/enum/enum_use.html) has the following example code:

```
enum Status {
    Rich,
    Poor,
}

fn main() {
    use crate::Status::{Poor, Rich};
    let status = Poor;

    match status {
        // Note the lack of scoping because of the explicit `use` above.
        Rich => println!("The rich have lots of money!"),
        Poor => println!("The poor have no money..."),
    }
}
```

which, as expected, returns:

> The poor have no money...

However, I was experimenting a bit and altered the code to:

```
enum Status {
    Rich,
    Poor,
}

fn main() {
    use crate::Status::Poor;
    let status = Poor;

    match status {
        // Note the lack of scoping because of the explicit `use` above.
        Rich => println!("The rich have lots of money!"),
        Poor => println!("The poor have no money..."),
    }
}
```

I was half-expecting a compile-error, but what I didn't understand is, why that code gives me:

> The rich have lots of money!

**Can somebody explain to me, what is going on here?**

Comment: Read the compiler warnings…

Comment: @mcarton Well, I ran the code on [the page it came from](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/custom_types/enum/enum_use.html)  and it didn't give any compiler warnings. I guess they are turned off there...

Comment: Your altered code does have warnings though.

Comment: @mcarton You misunderstood. The code does have warnings (which are helpful) when compiled form the command line. However, I was using the in-browser run of the "Rust by example" site which apparently has switched compiler warnings off (it shows compiler errors). That's why I missed it.

Comment: This is a case where an IDE can also makes it easier to spot the issue. IntelliJ IDEA, for example, uses a different typeface and color for enum variant names vs. variables, so `Rich` and `Poor` would have looked different from each other in that pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didn't specified `Status::Rich` it is taking it as a "match any and assign to Rich", the second match is basically unreachable since the first one will match everything.

Think of it, as a variable named Rich instead of the enum.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Status {
    Rich,
    Poor,
}

fn main() {
    use crate::Status::Poor;
    let status = Poor;

    match status {
        matched_status => println!("the status matched was {:?}", matched_status),
        Poor => unreachable!()
    }
}
```